# Expected method to read array element not found on object of type NSDictionary*

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I know there's a lot of questions like this around, but I think my situation's a tad different.

```
    int i = 0;
    while (_data[@"VerticalState%i", i] != nil) {
        // do things
        i++;
    }
```

For example, one 'level' that has 3 VerticalState properties will be implemented as such: VerticalState0, VerticalState1, VerticalState2.

I want to read in those values using that while loop condition above, and it should stop when i = 3.  How can I make the idea of that code above work (with some other configuration obviously).  FYI, `_data` is an `NSDictionary*` instance variable, already loaded with the plist information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want to create a dictionary key from a string format. You need to use `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

```
while (_data[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VerticalState%i", i]] != nil) {
```

Though it would be better to write the loop like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (1) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"VerticalState%i", i];
    id value = _dict[key];
    if (value) {
        // do things
        i++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Care to explain what you believe is wrong?

Comment: I didn't vote down...don't know who did.  But what you wrote got rid of the problem.  And that'll be good to use for reading in plist properties? The key being "VerticalState%i".

Comment: Yes, the code in my answer will iterate through your dictionary looking for the keys `VerticalState0`, `VerticalState1`, etc. until the key isn't found.

Comment: @Frank If you got solution for your problem then please accept the answer.

Comment: Here's a follow up question.  Let's say the key @"VerticalState%i" is an NSDictionary, will I still be able to use that NSString method to determine which NSDictionary I am trying to obtain information from? (Given that I still have VerticalState1, VerticalState2, etc.)

Comment: @Frank I'm not following. How can a string be a dictionary? What do you mean?

Comment: So I have a plist, and 'VerticalState%i' is actually a dictionary title.  Contained in a VerticalState%i dictionary (and many other similar dictionaries) are Column and Row NSNumber values.  So in my while loop, I wanted to evaluate if that particular dictionary could be found based on its lettering.  I don't know if that's the right way of doing things.  So, given that I'll have multiple similar-titled dictionaries, how should I go about evaluating such a situation? Should I use an NSArray instead?

Comment: This sounds like a whole new question requiring a log more details. Close this question out and post a new question with lots of details about this new question.